# IAP with Google Identity Platform throws "Failed to fetch the discovery document from issuer"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, openid, google-iam

I have activated Identity Aware Proxy on a GCP Load Balancer and configured it to authenticate the users against my OIDC Identity Provider (Auth0) through Google Identity Platform with a default login page hosted on Cloud Run.

When I browse my application I got redirected to the login page but then this happens:

[image: Failed to fetch the discovery document from issuer]

although the document is available and publicly reachable at that URL:

[image: Auth0 discovery document]

I followed [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enable-external-identities#enabling_to_use_external_identities) step by step and cannot find any troubleshooting guide. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: The OpenID Connect Metadata Document is public information. There is no need to mask that information. By hiding that information, we cannot run tests for you.

Comment: Hi John, I know it's public but I hope you appreciate I need to redact my Company's name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.

The problem was I had configured my Google Identity Platform OIDC Provider with the full metadata document URL

[image: wrong URL]

while only the issuer base URL was expected

[image: right URL]

Newbie mistake, I know, but the error message is misleading, IMO, because it reports the URL where the document actually is. If the returned message had been

```
Failed to fetch the discovery document from issuer: https://REDACTED.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

the misconfiguration would have been immediately apparent.